# How to fix "No such file or directory..." error due to C++ includePath

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-code, include-path

I am trying to include multiple hpp files in my code, however the include path option in my c_cpp_properties.json doesn't seem to be working correctly. I keep getting the "No such file or directory..." even though the correct files are there.

I have added the path to the includePath section of the c_cpp_properties.json file and it still isnt finding the files.

Include Part of Main File:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include <D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\highgui.hpp>
#include <D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
```

c_cpp_properties.json File:

````
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "D:/OpenCV/opencv/build/include",
                "D:/OpenCV/opencv/sources/modules/core/include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.17763.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}```

The file should run, but this error is causing it not to.
````

Comment: Since you already add `"D:/OpenCV/opencv/build/include"` as an include path, you don't need the full path for the OpenCV header files. And perhaps try with *forward* slashes (`/`) for the header files instead?

Comment: Also, I'm assuming you're using Visual Studio Code, so I added it as a tag.

Comment: I suspect that is a very safe assumption `:)`

Comment: `#include <D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\core.hpp>` is likely part of your problem. Note that you need to get it working without a full path here because opencv headers will include other opencv headers.

Comment: ***How to fix “No such file or directory…”*** You will most likely have to spend some time debugging your paths. Do the headers exist in the paths that you have added? Look at the opencv headers that you included. They will contain includes. Are these include paths relative to a path that you added?

Comment: `#include` directives should always use forward slashes, not backslashes. Forward slashes work fine even on Windows, and never get interpreted as escape sequences (e.g. `this\that` becomes `this<TAB>hat`).

Answer (score 1):

If `c_cpp_properties.json` contains properties used when compiling, your `#include`s should probably look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
```

The single backslashes you have in your `#include`s are most probably interpreted as the start of [escape sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) which will not result in correct paths.